# Pine Script using previous RSI crossover points as reference for new crossover

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to Pine Script and coding in general, so this is probably a newbie question :/
Is there any way to save/notate the percentage levels of past RSI crossover points to see whether a current crossover point is higher or lower than the previous ones?

### Thanks!

```
//@version=4


study(title="K-D Crossover30may")

Length = input(14, minval=1, title="Stochastic Length")
RSILength = input(9, minval=1, title="RSI Length")
smoothk = input(3, minval=1, title="Stochastic %K")
smoothd = input(4, minval=1, title="Stochastic %D")
RSI = rsi(close, RSILength)


BuyRangeLow = input(1, title="Buy Range Low")
BuyRangeHigh = input(34, title="Buy Range High")
SellRangeLow = input(68, title="Sell Range Low")
SellRangeHigh= input(99, title="Sell Range High")
hline(BuyRangeLow, title="Buy Range Low", color=color.green)
hline(BuyRangeHigh, title="Buy Range High", color=color.green)
hline(SellRangeLow, title="Sell Range Low", color=color.red)
hline(SellRangeHigh, title="Sell Range High", color=color.red)

stoch = stoch(RSI, RSI, RSI, Length)

K =sma(stoch, smoothk)
D =sma(K, smoothd)

plot(K, title="%K", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(D, title="%D", color=color.yellow, linewidth=2)

CrossedUp = crossover(K, D) and D >6 and D <= BuyRangeHigh
CrossedDown = crossunder(K, D) and D >= SellRangeLow

bgcolor(CrossedUp ? color.green : na, transp=50)
bgcolor(CrossedDown ? color.red : na, transp=50)

var a = valuewhen(CrossedUp, D, open, 0)
var b = valuewhen(CrossedUp, D, open, 1)
var c = valuewhen(CrossedUp, D, open, 2)

if (var a > var b) 
      if (var b > var c) 
        bgcolor=color.blue
```

Comment: Hello and welcometo StakOverflow, please share the code you tried to write for this problem. Please also take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks good to me and it should work as you described. There are just a couple of minor mistakes in it.

First, `valuewhen` takes three parameters, not four. The second parameter is a series that is used to read the value on a bar when the condition is true. I believe, it should be `D` or `K` in your case.

And second, `bgcolor` is a function, do not assign a value to it, just call it:

```
a = valuewhen(CrossedUp, D, 0)
b = valuewhen(CrossedUp, D, 1)
c = valuewhen(CrossedUp, D, 2)

bgcolor(a > b and b > c ? color.blue : na, transp=50)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. Much appreciated!

Comment: @user3881559 I'm happy to help. Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your problem. Thank you.